# Convert SQL query to LINQ with subquery

Tags: linq

I don't know linq but I need to create a linq query for this SQL query

```
SELECT a.[ProjectId], 
            a.[CompanyId],          
            a.[Status], 
            ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 1 
                      FROM [dbo].[Project] b 
                     WHERE b.[MasterProjectId] = a.[MasterProjectId] 
                       AND b.[Level] > 1), 0) [HasSubProjects] 
       FROM [dbo].[Project] a
```

Comment: Surely it should be `WHERE b.[MasterProjectId] = a.[ProjectId]`? Anyway, show the class model, so we don't have to guess which classes and properties you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = con.Projects;
var ret = d.Select(x => new { 
    x.ProjectId,
    x.CompanyId,
    x.Status,
    HasSubProjects = d.Any(y=> y.MasterProjectId == x.MasterProjectId && y.Level > 1) ? 1 : 0
})
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**